# How do I use parameters with OrmLiteReadConnectionExtensions.Select(...) passing in a parameterized SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I have a project that's using ServiceStack & ORMLite.  I need to make use of the `OrmLiteReadConnectionExtensions` extension method `List<T> Select<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn, string sqlFilter, params object[] filterParams)`.

The thing is, I can't find any documentation or references on how to use this method with a SQL select statement and parameters.

When I looked up the code in github, the following sample/hint was provided:

```
db.Select<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age > @age", new[] { db.CreateParam("age", 40) })
```

This would makes sense, but the problem is that my ORMLite c reated db (an `IDbConnection` object) doesn't have a db.CreateParam(...) method.
How can I create and execute a parameterized select query for my ORMLite repository?  To be clear, I am user Sql Server with this project.

Answer (score 2):

[OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) does have the [IDbConnection.CreateParam()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/5e375153073befd6da2c90f56479cef2e1e8a2c4/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/SqlExpression.cs#L3014) extension method.

Have a look at the [SelectParamTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/SelectParamTests.cs) for different examples for providing parameters in OrmLite:

```
db.Select<Person>(x => x.Age == 27)
db.Select(db.From<Person>().Where(x => x.Age == 27))
db.Select<Person>("Age = @age", new { age = 27 })
db.Select<Person>("Age = @age", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "age", 27 } })
db.Select<Person>("Age = @age", new[] { db.CreateParam("age", 27) })
db.Select<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new { age = 27 })
db.Select<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "age", 27 } })
db.Select<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new[] { db.CreateParam("age", 27) })

db.Select<Person>("Age = @age", new { age = 27 })

db.SelectNonDefaults(new Person { Age = 27 })

db.SqlList<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new { age = 27 })
db.SqlList<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "age", 27 } })
db.SqlList<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = @age", new[] { db.CreateParam("age", 27) })
```